# App crashes when the input data to write on txt is bigger than 16kb (C programming)

Tags: c, file, input, io, output

I'm trying to make a program which gets inputs from txt file (coordinates like x1,x2) and store it on element to write in SVG format. The code I wrote below works actually. The problem is when I get input bigger than 16kb, while writing on svg file application crashes. So I cannot find the problem actually. It should be about "strcat(str_joined, svg[i].xy);" this since I'm joining so much string into one string variable.

Input Example :

```
339, 52
339, 52
339, 52
338, 53
338, 53
337, 54
337, 54
337, 54
337, 55
337, 55
336, 56
336, 56
336, 56
336, 57
335, 57
335, 56
334, 56
334, 56
333, 56
332, 56
332, 56
331, 56
331, 56
330, 56
330, 56
329, 56
```

Output Example : `<svg><polyline points='339,52 339,52 339,52 338,53 338,53 337,54 '/></svg>`

And Code : I just put the generate_svg part of the code.

```
void generate_svg(char *input, char *output)
{         
    //INPUT OPERATİONS //

FILE *fp;
int array_size = 0, i=0, max_lines = 0;  // Line counters
char c;  // To store a character read from file to check whether newline or not
char *str_joined = NULL;

// Open the file
fp = fopen(input, "r");

//Count the number of lines for the array size 
for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    if (c == '\n') 
        array_size = array_size + 1;
fclose(fp);


// read the file into an array of coordinates
Coord *coord = malloc(array_size * sizeof *coord); //preallocation for performance
fp = fopen(input, "r");
while(!feof(fp))
{
   //check whether input getting correctly             
   if(fscanf(fp, "%d, %d", &coord[i].x, &coord[i].y)==2)      
      i++;           
}
fclose(fp);

//OUTPUT OPERATIONS
max_lines = i;
SVG *svg = malloc(array_size * sizeof *svg); // allocate memory
size_t total_length=0, length=0; //total length and length of string
for(i=0; i<max_lines; i++)
{
    sprintf(svg[i].xy , "%d,%d ", coord[i].x, coord[i].y);
    total_length += strlen(svg[i].xy); 
    //printf("%s\n", svg[i].xy);
}

str_joined = (char*)malloc(total_length * sizeof *str_joined); // allocate memory for joined strings
str_joined[0] = '\0'; // empty string we can append to

for(i=0; i<max_lines; i++)
{
         strcat(str_joined, svg[i].xy);
         length = strlen(str_joined);

         str_joined[length+1] = '\0';           /* followed by terminator */

}

FILE *fp_out;
fp_out = fopen(output,"w+"); //erase the content and write on it if exists or create the file and write on it

if(fp_out == NULL)
{
  printf("Error");           
}
else
{
  fprintf(fp_out, "<svg><polyline points='%s'/></svg>" , str_joined);

   printf("Operation successful.\n");
}
//printf("%s\n", str_joined);
```

}

So any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

//UPDATE

Header:

```
//definitions
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100
#define OUTPUT_FILE_NAME "svg_output.svg"

void generate_svg(char *input, char *output);
//storage for coordinates
typedef struct Coord
{
    int x;
    int y;
}Coord;

typedef struct SVG
{
  char xy[20];        

}SVG;
```

[So application crash image :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP1IR.jpg)

Comment: Where does it crash ? Your debugger will tell you. Also please show the calling code as well as variable and type declarations such as `SVG`.

Comment: Note that `getc` returns an `int`. `EOF` may not fit in a `char`. Declare `c` as an `int`.

Comment: Your `total_length` doesn't include space for a null-terminator.

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `sizeof(char)` is always 1 per definition.

Comment: Sİnce I'm using devc++ it shows nothing :)) I also tried in Visual Studio without precompiler header and set as C compiler, I got the malloc problem which says you cannot be initialized with the type "Coord". I'm updating my post with the header parts.

Comment: Try `malloc(total_length * 2)` just for testing purposes. If it doesn't crash anymore, then the problem is probably that you don't allocate enough memory and you write beyont the allocated memory.

Comment: Kninnug, I have no problem in that part I know it.  For example instead of writing with fprintf, I just type like printf("%s", str_joined); it works correctly ?

Comment: @Michael Walz, I tried what you saying but it still crashes :(

Comment: Test  if `fp` is NULL after `fp = fopen(input, "r");`.

Comment: @Michael Walz, it doesnt work either. Also I'm using w+ flag which means create file if not exist or delete all content write on it. So it doesnt really matter to check whether ftp_out is null or not

Comment: **Never** assume `fopen` succeeds. It can fail for a lot of (sometimes unexpected) reasons

Comment: So what you are suggesting me. I must do this in C, I'm even better in C++ but This is required like this for the work.

Comment: @Destroy we suggest you 1: check your `fopen` calls for `NULL`s. 2: use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead of `sprintf` to prevent overflow. 3: `malloc` string-length + 1 for your strings, don't cast the result but do check if it isn't `NULL`.

Comment: I check fopen whether it is null or not. I looked at the malloc issue and fixed it i guess. But nothing changed right now. So finally, I'm going to check the "snprintf", After checking I will write the result again.

Comment: @Destroy can you tell us **where excatly** the crash occurs and what is the error message you get ?

Comment: I'm getting crash when the buffer is writtin in svg file. I know since when I change it to printf to check the buffer is correct. It is correct. But I tested that when the buffer size bigger than 16-18 kb I'm getting this crash. For instance, when I got input as 40 kb, when the writing process, it crashes. I'm not getting any error message because of the stupidity of devexpress. Now, I'm trying to compile with gcc.

Comment: @Kninnug, I tested but ı have no problem with sprintf either. It gets any buffer in anysize without any error. So let me see what's going to happen when compiling in gcc. I'll write soon

Comment: So, I compiled with GCC but there is no error as not in devexpress. I have getting crash without any warning while program running. Cant get it really :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Thanks for the helps really. I solved the problem. I configured the Visual Studio for C compiling and also standardized my code as C99. So final shape of my code is the following and it works.

```
void generate_svg(char *input, char *output)
{

    //INPUT OPERATİONS //

    FILE *fp, *fp_out;  SVG *svg;  Coord *coord;
    int array_size = 0, i=0, max_lines = 0;  // Line counters
    char c;  // To store a character read from file to check whether newline or not
    char *str_joined = NULL;
    size_t total_length=0, length=0;

    // Open the file
    fp = fopen(input, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error");
    }
    else
    {
         //Count the number of lines for the array size 
        for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
            if (c == '\n') 
                array_size = array_size + 1;
        fclose(fp);
    }




    // read the file into an array of coordinates
    coord = (Coord*)malloc(array_size * sizeof(Coord)); //preallocation for performance
    fp = fopen(input, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
           //check whether input getting correctly             
           if(fscanf(fp, "%d, %d", &coord[i].x, &coord[i].y)==2)      
              i++;           

        }
        fclose(fp);
    }


    //OUTPUT OPERATIONS
    max_lines = i;
    svg = (SVG*)malloc(array_size * sizeof(SVG)); // allocate memory
     //total length and length of string
    for(i=0; i<max_lines; i++)
    {
        sprintf(svg[i].xy , "%d,%d ", coord[i].x, coord[i].y);
        total_length += strlen(svg[i].xy); 
        //printf("%s\n", svg[i].xy);
    }

    str_joined = (char*)malloc(total_length * 2); // allocate memory for joined strings
    str_joined[0] = '\0'; // empty string we can append to

    for(i=0; i<max_lines; i++)
    {
        strcat(str_joined, svg[i].xy);

    }

    fp_out = fopen(output,"w+"); //erase the content and write on it if exists or create the file and write on it
    if (fp_out==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(fp_out, "<svg><polyline points='%s'/></svg>" , str_joined);
        printf("Operation successful.\n");
    }


    //printf("%s\n", str_joined);




}
```